# Google Charts: Stop from rounding up?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a simple problem, but maybe not a simple solution. I do not have much experience with javascript and the google charts api.

I have an array with numbers in the range of 0.0006 to 0.0009. But if I plot it with a chart, it rounds that up to 0.001, on the vAxis and on the tooltip when I go with the mouse on the chart line.

How do I get to show x places after the decimal point instead of rounding up? Or change the point where it rounds up.

thx.

Comment: Partially solved: I found the format options, but I mistook a . for a ,. Using format: '#.####'  I get the values on the axis, but not yet on the mouse hover tooltip

Answer (score 1):

to format the number in the tooltip,
you need to format the data in the data table

you can use a number formatter,

```
formatPattern = '#,##0.0000';
var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  pattern: formatPattern
});
```

then use the format method, pass in the data table and the column index to be formatted...

```
formatNumber.format(data, 1);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [0, 0.0006],
    [1, 0.0007],
    [2, 0.0008],
    [3, 0.0009],
    [4, 0.0005]
  ], true);

  formatPattern = '#,##0.0000';
  var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: formatPattern
  });
  formatNumber.format(data, 1);

  var options = {
    pointSize: 4,
    vAxis: {
      format: formatPattern
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```